# How to strip headers from all files in RDD, where RDD = sc.textFile("s3n://bucket/*.csv")?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, header, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to think of the best way to do this, however, I am unable to think of a way that would not include reading headers from all files into array, and then filtering the RDD from those headers.

Is there a simpler way ?

NOTE: I am reading all csv files from a S3 bucket, and all of those files have a different header.

Comment: Is using `wholeTextFiles` an option? It is a little more manual, but it seems that you might need that.

Comment: It is an option, as long as I get the same RDD type at the end that I would get with textFile.

Comment: A simple solution is to just `filter` out the header. Of course this will filter out all lines that _look_ like the header, but why would you have such lines anyway.

Comment: @Daniel, how do I know which line is like a header when I do a textFile onto a whole s3 bucket? All rows that I have are alpha-numeric.  I need this for a NLP system, so it needs to be very flexible.

Comment: Are the headers alphanumeric as well? In that case you need a proper solution.

Comment: Yes, I do need a proper solution :) It looks like the only option I have is to read the headers separately, and then filter the RDDs from it... not an elegant solution but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use SparkSQL, which can load CSV with the option to ignore the header. Take a look:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

> header: when set to true the first line of files will be used to name columns and will not be included in data. All types will be assumed string. Default value is false.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, and I like it!  How would I take all files from a S3 bucket as one RDD using this approach ? Do I really need to save the file (saving will not help since I have at least 40mil. rows) ? Would it be possible to obtain some source code solving this issue ? (It will also help others looking for the same answer) Thank you!